# Why I'm not selected in an interview?

Tags: interview

I'm working in development for 4 years, and 3.5 in PHP - why I don't seem to be able to be selected in an interview.

I want to know what special things the interviewer wants to see in candidates - for senior PHP developer roles.

Interviewer asks me 10 questions and I'm able to answer only 5. Does selection depend on these things? It doesn't mean that I can't solve the problem, I can google the question, I can ask on forums. Why don't they understand that a man can't remember all the answers for each and every question? Especially programming ones.

Please advise.

Comment: @Rook please check now

Comment: If you really want to "WoW" them in the interview : [See this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329289/really-wow-them-in-the-interview)

Comment: Maybe they google your name, find this question and reason "Hm, apparently others have not taken him in for an interview. He's probably a bad candidate for this job, too".

Comment: Which questions were you unable to answer?

Comment: It's unfortunate that the fact that you were looking for a Senior PHP Developer position was edited out of your question, as that may be the reason you are not being selected. Four years of experience does not qualify you for a senior level position at most employers.

Comment: I guess because you suck.

Comment: Senior PHP developer... The mind boggles...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*"Interviewer asks me 10 questions and I'm able to answer only 5. Does selection depend on these things? It doesn't mean that I can't solve the problem, I can google the question, I can ask on forums. Why don't they understand that a man can't remember all the answers for each and every question? Expecially programming ones."*

These things are very significant and will be a very significant part of the reason.

Interviewers do understand that you can't know everything and generally tailor the questions to suit.   Generally most questions an interviewer will ask will be the sorts of things they expect a candidate to be able to answer **without** access to the internet.

Why do they expect this standard?  A few reasons come to mind:

1. You indicate that you're looking at senior developer roles.  Senior
   developers are by definition those who have a good level of
   knowledge already and can help others out, not those who are
   dependent on Google.
2. A programmer who knows this stuff - as opposed to having to post it
   on forums - is going to be far more productive that one who relies
   on the internet.  They're not having to wait for replies, understand
   what's been posted and adapt it to their purpose, they're just
   getting on and coding.
3. They're obviously finding candidates who can answer these questions
   and in that instance wouldn't you hire the guy who got 9 out of 10
   over the guy who got 5 out of 10.
4. If they were happy with someone bright who understands the basics
   and Googles the rest, you can hire a junior developer for a lot less
   money.

Personally out of 10 questions for an intermediate or senior role normally I'd expect a candidate to be answering perhaps 8 well and having a fair idea at least one of the others.

If you're not hitting that level then I suggest that you're probably applying for jobs a little above your current level and should adjust your expectations.

Answer (score 31):

Reason 1 : You have bad English

Comment: that is not the reason for selection , my english is not that bad

Comment: Less important in india than in your country maybe.

Comment: +1 That may or may not be a put down, but you've managed to stumble across what studies have shown to be the most important aspect of a potential employee: communication skills (more important than education or experience).

Comment: Reason 2: you are unable to assess your language skills correctly

Comment: @Rahul - are you interviewing in English?

Comment: @jon yes i interview in english

Comment: @Rahul - then I think you need to consider that it might be a factor.  People aren't being rude but your English could be better and it might be influencing some people.

Comment: @Rahul: Consider that your question has received 1 major and 1 minor grammar edit, and it could still use some more. **I'm** not saying it's the reason you're being turned down, but you're not being honest with yourself if you think it's not that bad.

Comment: I disagree. Based on the original post @Rahul's English is good enough to communicate effectively. Minor grammar mistakes can be disregarded for a non-native speaker. Real problem is the  **disregard for details**, reflected in sloppy spelling and capitalization. It looks like the writer is **not making any effort** to be presentable and accurate. Programmers tend to be meticulous. A misplaced capital, comma or even whitespace hurt our eyes. Sloppiness is a huge red flag.

Comment: @dbkk I interview for software engineers and designers, and the most important single aspect we look for, is "attention to detail".  Coding relies on precision, UI design does too, communications between colleagues can introduce untold calamity if poorly worded.

Comment: @SnOrfus I agree my english is bad

Comment: @Jon Agree with you

Comment: @dbkk agree with you

Answer (score 18):

I've said it before. I'll say it again.

**A job interview is a competition, not a pass-fail test.**

The reason you aren't getting the job is that another candidate impressed the employer more than you did. If you got 5 questions right, perhaps someone else got 6 or more.

The fact that you can Google answers or get them from SO is irrelevant as I discussed in more detail in my blog article [Why "I'd just Google it" is not an acceptable interview answer](http://improvingsoftware.com/2009/05/15/why-id-just-google-it-is-not-an-acceptable-interview-answer/).

Comment: +1: Anyone can google. You have to demonstrate that you're better than a googler.

Comment: @SnOrfus: Or at least better than the googlers who are applying for the same job.

Comment: @JohnFx: Of course, yes. If you only ever want _that_ job.

Comment: @SnOrfus, actually it is an art to use Google - you need to know the right terms for what you want to know or you will never find the needle in the haystack.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Not if you recursively search. ie. 1) Search for whatever you think it is 2) Read, find keywords, put those keywords back into your search 3) Rinse and repeat until you find what you need. This method will always lead, invariably, to information sufficient for what you're looking for (if it exists) - just not always in a timely fashion. Hence, anyone can google. Some will just get to a solution faster if they have programming and domain knowledge to start out with.

Comment: @SnOrfus, I wouldn't call that "Just use Google" anymore.

Comment: Despite all that. Would you pick a candidate who answered the question directly, or one who gave you a lecture on how good they were at Google?

Comment: @JohnFx, good candidates are also in a position to select their employer. If they feel like they are being weeded out by their employer, or that the interview proceeds in a pointless or condescending fashion, then they will not accept a position. When I first started interviewing, on occasion I felt - if only I was more senior, more experienced, I could answer their questions fairly well, and then walk out in the middle of it just to teach them some manners. But, I had to cling to EVERY learning opportunity, and had to withstand some abuse.

Comment: @Job I don't think the OP would be asking this question if he were in a position to select his employer.

Answer (score 5):

**If you aren't getting interviews** then it could be that your 3½ to 4 years experience isn't seen as sufficient for a *senior* developer role. You should look at revising your CV to highlight your strengths. You should also look at applying for more relevant roles - perhaps at a more junior level.

**If you are getting interviews** then it could be down to anything.

You might come over as too nervous/shy **or** you might come over as too abrasive/aggressive
**or** ....

Ultimately only the interviewer can answer this question and they might not even be able to articulate the answer themselves - they just "know" you won't fit in.

Comment: what is mean by nervous shy abrasive and aggressive , why these things matter for an interviewer

Comment: @Rahul - someone in a senior position needs to be able to "get on" and communicate well with others. This will include other developers, sales people and even customers. Being too shy or too aggressive would be problematical. The examples weren't meant to be a complete list just examples of why you might have failed.

Comment: how can he judge that i am shy or aggressive

Comment: @Rahul - from how you behave **in the interview**. However, if you **aren't** getting to interview then you need to focus on your CV and the type of roles you are applying for.

Comment: If, having had an interview, you are not selected there is nothing wrong with going back (writing) to the company and asking why they didn't choose you - the worst that happens is that they tell you nothing or give you a stock answer, the best is that you learn for next time.

Comment: @Murph No, in the best case scenario they inadvertently reveal that you were passed over due to illegal discrimination and sue the for millions of dollars. It is, however, not a likely scenario.

Comment: All that the interviewer has to go on is your CV and your observable behavior in the interview. Behavior is: 1) what you say (the actual words); 2) HOW you say it (your tone, speed of speech, clarity, etc.); 3) Facial expression (do you not look at the interviewer when you speak, or do you stare? Do you look bored, or interested?); and 4) Body language (are you hunched up? do you LOOK relaxed?). The only other observable behavior is your work product, and all they have is your CV. It might not seem "fair" but this is all that they have to go on. They will for a judgment based on all this.

Comment: I know this is going to sound rude, but I'm not sure how to put it more gently - if you can Google the answers to questions, why can't you Google nervous/shy/abrasive/aggressive?

Comment: @Rahul I am surprised you ask why nervousness, shyness or being abrasive would matter to an interviewer.  That leads me to believe that you expect to work independently from anyone else and not have to speak to clients ever.  Every member of a company must be able to fit-in well with their colleagues and be able to talk amicably and smoothly with clients.

Comment: @Orling i agree these things matter.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: *this answer has been made based on the first version of the question, which asked "why i am not selected in interview"*

Show us your CV and we'll tell you.

Did you...

- ... put your photo? Remove it
- ... put emphasis on your problem solving capabilities?
- ... send it to enough companies? (To get one interview, you must send 10 CV)
- ... have too much pages? Limit your CV to one page
- ... send it to companies that actually need PHP?
- ... tried different versions of your CV?

Comment: How to put emphasis on problem solving capability?

Comment: how can i upload my cv  it to this page

Comment: please check my cv here http://rahuldeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/11/my-cv.html

Comment: Are you sending that page to companies?

Comment: @Pierre  not this page i am sending word file of this post

Comment: First thing you could do is removing this: http://i.imgur.com/9QcAV.jpg.

Comment: @Pierre i have done this

Comment: The other problem I see that may affect your conversion rate is how you position yourself. I see "senior programmer" many times, but the only relevant professional experience I see in your CV is late 2006. India is a very competitive market.

Comment: i was senior programmer in these companies so i have written that what you suggest

Comment: I'd disagree on "Limit your CV to one page", I think 2 pages of a4 is perfectly acceptable. Certainly in the uk, its the norm.

Comment: @Gruffputs: please disagree there: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18803/how-many-pages-is-your-resume. Your valuable feedback will be available to others, including the user that asked the question. Thanks

Comment: @rahul, change the summary at the top from a summary of experience to a summary of your current skills without reference to which position you obtained that experience.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the CV - you're getting interviews.  If they give you an interview the chances of you getting rejected because of something on the CV is minimal.

Comment: @Jon: Rahul changed updated question after this answer. Check revisions. Initially, he was complaining about not getting interviewed at all.

Comment: @Pierre - Ah, OK.  Came late to the party.

Comment: 1 interview for each 10 CVs sent? That seems like a pretty awful ratio.

Comment: @JohnFx: yes that's the minimum we could expect in competitive india.

Comment: has anybody actually looked at the CV's HTML code? It's exported from MS Word. Not what I would expect from a Senior PHP developer...

Comment: @JohnFx I can not remember the exact statistic, but in London (where I am from), I think an average IT position gets about 300 applications.  If you are getting 1 interview out of 10 applications here, you are doing *very* well.

Comment: Yikes. Is the IT job market really that bad over there. I get nowhere close to 300 applications when I post a job. Of course I work at a pretty small company.

Answer (score 4):

By the sounds of it, you would fail my interview technique as well. At interview I expect candidates to write code on the whiteboard.  It might seem tough, but it allows candidates to show that they do know the language, and are not relying on intelsense and google to program.  Lets face it, if you are claiming on your CV to have 3.5 years of PHP experience, then at interview I want to see some evidence of your experience.

I also use the process to identify people that think logically about their designs, write code that actually implements their design, and when faced with a new constraint understand how it affects their design, and what they need to adjust to accommodate this new information.

Whilst lots of companies do use the 20 question interview method, this method is a poor differentiator in identifying who the best programmers are, and good at identifying who has been reading a lot of books recently.  If you are constantly facing this interview technique, start reading.  You should want a 95-100% good answer rate on these questions to get offered the job, however it will not make you a better programmer on its own.

The major problem with "*programming by google*" is that whilst you may deliver code that works, but its quite possible that you have no understanding of it increasing the risk of subtle bugs and undesirable consequences. It will certainly take longer to write the code and your source code will have the same consistency as the internet making it much harder for your replacement to support your code in the future.

Whilst I'm sure that my answer is not the warm fuzzy reassurance that you may have wanted, hopefully it will help you to understand what you need to do differently to gain the knowledge and experience, or perhaps, may help you to understand why a career in a different sector may be a better choice for you.  good luck for the future.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you wrote the question whilst frustrated - but this suggests a problem:

> Interviewer asks me 10 questions and
>   I'm able to answer only 5. Does
>   selection depend on these things? It
>   doesn't mean that I can't solve the
>   problem, I can google the question, I
>   can ask on forums. Why don't they
>   understand that a man can't remember
>   all the answers for each and every
>   question? Expecially programming ones

I have two issues with this, first is that if you answer 5 out of 10 and someone else answers 6 out of 10 then all other things being equal that's game over - but second and more important is the question of how you respond when you don't know and your attitude to not knowing.

In terms of questions - it rather depends on the questions - but if its basic platform knowledge then you should be able to answer and if its a more detailed problem then you should be able to suggest approaches - "look on google and ask in forums" is not an approach.  Any programmer I interviewed that suggested either a) that he knew everything (unlikely and probably already proven to be false by poor answers) or b) that he didn't need to because all the answers were on google (or even stackoverflow) would not be coming back.

In terms of attitude... if you're being interviewed by someone qualified to ask the questions then they will have their own view of what a reasonable level of knowledge is based on their own capabilities and experience and you know what? It may be reasonable for a given job to expect the interviewee to give a good answer to most of their questions. If you're consistently failing to answer a significant number of questions (50% is significant) then you need to assess why.

Answer (score 1):

I always tell people to try asking the interviewer that turned you down what might have improved your candidacy. Even if you get a response from 1 out of 10 interviewers, you won't be guessing (or asking others to guess).

I ask every time, have only ever had one person refuse, and I **always** get great feedback. The sample size is low though (4).

Answer (score 0):

Another point is how many people are applying for these jobs?  If there are a dozen or more being interviewed and you all have an equal chance of getting the position, the probability is around 8.3% you realize, right?  Sometimes it can come down to a numbers game where you have to go through many interviews to get somewhere.

How many people can match your PHP experience but may have more education or some other differentiating factor?  When you don't answer a question, are you saying that you'd go to Google and have it answer the question for you?  How you phrase something like that could make it come off like the company is hiring someone when they should just get a contract with Google to get the answers.  While some may think that is ridiculous, there are many things in this world that are rather ridiculous yet exist.

Last but not least, there can also be the potential for you wanting something that a company isn't going to give.  For example, how many companies would pay a developer $1,000,000,000 (US) or more?  Very few if any, I'd think.  What kinds of questions are you asking the company?  What kinds of signs are you showing that you want the job and would fit into their culture?  If you make it sound like the company should be lucky that you are even considering working *there*, that arrogance may well be a contributing factor on why a company doesn't like you.